# Amazon SES inbound email delivery failed 4.3.0 451

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, smtp, amazon-ses

I have set up a rule set for inbound emails in AWS SES. This inbound rule receives an email and a lambda function processes the email content.

This worked up until a couple of days ago when I started receiving the error message below when sending emails to the address connected to the inbound rule:

```
4.3.0 smtp; 451 4.3.0 This message could not be delivered due to a recipient error. Please try again later
```

However - the rule still triggers the corresponding lambda function which means that the email is actually delivered.

How can I prevent the server from sending this response?

Comment: Is the Lambda function failing to exit successfully?

Comment: The lambda does not crash or time out

Answer (score 3):

Under `Actions` in `Email receiving` add a `Stop rule set` action where it should stop checking additional rules.[image]

Answer (score 2):

The lambda function that I thought was causing this was not the culprit in this case.

There was another rule in place which failed since it did not have access to the S3 bucket in which is was supposed to save incoming emails.

Lesson learned: This error message is sent back from the email server when an incoming SES rule fails to exit successfully.

Comment: +1. I had an action in the ruleset that triggered a Lambda function which was deleted a while back. Removing that action from the ruleset solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody comes across this in future and Karl's solution isn't the issue: I had this exact issue and it turned out the **action ordering** was causing the error.

If the Lambda function action was *before* the S3 action, it threw the `4.3.0 smtp; 451 4.3.0 This message could not be delivered due to a recipient error. Please try again later` error, even though the flow worked as expected. If you swap them over so it is S3 then lambda, it works fine.